# c# Polling external device in separate thread every 100 milliseconds

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I would like to build a program, which will communicate with some external device every 100 milliseconds in separate thread (other than UI thread). What I need is some mechanism of continual pooling.

This is my first encounter with multithreading and I don't know how to do it properly...

As far as I read I could use `System.Threading.Timer` class to not block user GUI.

Unfortunately I have problems at the beginning with my `TimerCallback` method. I'm trying to use `System.Threading.Timer` timer. Shortly after invoking `TimerCallback` program suddenly exits ... I don't understand why. Could someone help me explain this situation?

My code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Threading.Timer timer;
    TimerCallback tcb;

    private void btnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tcb = new TimerCallback(PoolingStart);

        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(tcb, null, 0, Timeout.Infinite);    
    }

    public void PoolingStart(object state)
    {
       dgvGrid.Rows.Add(); //while debugging program exits here ... Why ? 
       //some API for external device which retrieve data from it
       timer.Change(0, 100);
    }
}
```

I don't know if this approach is proper regarding pooling external devices though. 
Maybe there is a much better way to do this. maybe someone could prompt me some solution?
Anyway - here the problem is with `TimerCallback` method. The whole program exits shortly after calling `DataGridView` control.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and the project is in Windows Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the UI update in timer thread is illegal, you should change your update operation.

```
private void btnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(PoolingStart));
    timer.Change(0, 100);
}
public void PoolingStart(object state)
{
    this.dgvGrid.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { this.dgvGrid.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow()); }));            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining me what did I do wrong. Could you tell me something more about Lambda expression that you used in this example ? Why there are empty brackets during making Methodinvoker delegate ? `(new MethodInvoker(() => ...`

Answer (score 1):

*`while debugging program exits here ... Why`*

Because you are trying  to access a graphic control from another thread which is not allowed try  to use [**`Control.InvokeRequired`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before you  try  access to any property or method  of a control  from  another thread

Answer (score 1):

The program exits because you are trying to access a control (the *DataGrid*) from a thread which is not the its owner (in other words you are experimenting an illegal cross-thread exception).

If you want to update the content of some UI controls from a different thread then you need to use `Invoke` (blocking call) or `BeginInvoke` (non-blocking call).

Here on SO (or on the web in general) you should find tons of examples about that: if you need some specific info write here again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reactive Extensions [RX-WinForms](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-WinForms/) library.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const int PollIntervalMilliseconds = 100;
    private readonly Task _backgroundPoll;

    public Form1()
    {
        InititalizeComponents();
        _backgroundPoll = StartBackgroundPoll();
    }

    private Task StartBackgroundPoll()
    {
        return Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(PollIntervalMilliseconds))
            .Select(_ => GetData())
            .ObserveOn(gdvGrid)
            .ForEachAsync(data => gdvGrid.Rows.Add(data));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me something more about this library ? Am I using my own external device API within `GetDate()` method ? I mean `Observable.Select(_ => GetData())` ?